# Excel Changes number value automatically

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2010

I´m trying to remove the dollar sign in a column which should only include numbers. Therefore I tried to to use simply change the cell format to number but nothing changed.

Now I copied the values inside a text editor and removed the dollar signs. After inserting excel automaticallly changes some values to different numbers.

For Exaxmple it changed *8.59 to 21763,00*. When I change the cell format to standard then it displays me something like *28 Jan except 8.59*.

In this picture I tried to illustrate my problem with the different columns. Sold Price in Thousands is the original column which I liked to change.

[image]

Comment: Is this imported data?

Comment: Try using NUMBERVALUE - `=NUMBERVALUE(E2;".")`. Or you can fix this when importing the data, if that is the case.

Comment: @Davesexcel yes it´s imported data from a csv file.

Comment: @BigBen I imported the data in the data type of text to be able to work with this data without any formatting issues on excel side.

Comment: Could you link us to  the file so we can work on it?

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to fix and run this short macro:

```
Sub FixData()
    Dim r As Range, s As String

    For Each r In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        s = r.Text
        If Left(s, 1) = "$" Then
            r.Clear
            r.Value = Mid(s, 2)
            r.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like OP's decimal separator is the comma, not the period.

Answer (score 0):

this is a known issue and the only work around that you can use is the following:

1. Copy the correct values in notepad.
2. From notepad make a Find and Replace in order to remove the $ sign.
3. Select a blank column in excel and set its format to TEXT.
4. Only now you can copy back the values from notepad to the new TEXT column.

This should fix your issue.

Comment: "The only workaround that you can use is the following." I would say this is incorrect. There are *many* workarounds. Besides, OP probably wants *numbers*, not *text*.

Comment: Yes @BigBen is right. Of Course I´ve done it this way, but my aim is to get the values correct in a number format. When I change the format from number to text then it changes the values as I said before.